# Flask, Right way to delete record and related files/images

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

Do we have any built in feature to delete record along with images related to that record....

My record looks like this

[image]

I know this feature is available in Django with the help of signals.... do we have any similar feature in flask

**sample code for django**

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_delete
from django.dispatch import receiver
 
 
class MyModel(models.Model):
    """Model containing file field"""
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='somewhere', blank=False)
    ...
 
@receiver(post_delete, sender=MyModel)
def submission_delete(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.file.delete(False)
```

I can create a function which can delete the files before deleting that record, but I would like to know is there any official way to do it....

Comment: Just call a function when the user clicks on the `delete` button... What are you using `sqlalchemy`?

Comment: Yes, I am using sqlalchemy